# How to give input to python program through bash?

Tags: bash

I want to provide first argument of bash script as filename to python.

I tried this solution from another question:

```bash
python main.py <<EOF
$1
EOF
```

But python raises `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` , if you add another input in python program.

How to solve it?

Comment: What's wrong with ```python main.py "$1"```?

Comment: Why you are using EOF? why not simply use $1 or $2?

Comment: "if you add another input in python program." I can't understand the situation you are describing like this. Please read [ask] and [mre], and make it possible for others to reproduce the problem by copying and pasting example code and/or running example scripts in the exact way you describe.

Comment: @karlKnechtel I want my python program to take multiple inputs and first input should be given by bash program and other inputs by user.

Comment: @teal33t How? I don't know much about bash.

Comment: The bash script is only specifying the *command line* that will be used to run the Python program - i.e., arguments that will appear in `sys.argv`. If you also want to supply the *standard input* (i.e., data that can be read by `input`, i.e. which appears in `sys.stdin`), then you need to *pipe* it to the Python program. This is nothing to do with Python and purely a question about how the shell works. Please try to follow a command line tutorial if you are unfamiliar with these concepts.

Comment: "I tried this solution from another question" Please link it, so that we can see what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys` lib:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print (arg)

$ python test.py a b c
a
b
c
```

in your case it would be something like:

```
python test.py your/file/path input1 input2
```